# Using position: fixed for navigation not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've created a JSFiddle to show my webpage structure HTML and CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/du7NN/

I've been trying to build a page where when scrolling the navigation sticks to the top of the page while the rest of the reader disappears and rest of the page scrolls but when I add position:fixed on the .nav class It stops the background-color from spanning the whole width of the page and overrides my text-align: center. Here is the rest of my CSS:

```
.header {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav {
    position: fixed;
}

.nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;e
    list-style: none;
    /* display: block; */
    background-color: #eee;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

I've come across a few examples of how to fix this, but finding it hard to understand how to apply it to my issue.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I posted an answer, but I may have misunderstood your question. Are you wanting the nav to be below the header, for your h1 to scroll up, and then for your nav to stick to the top of the screen?

Comment: That would be really cool, I presumed it wouldn't be possible because of the way I have the navigation positioned? Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Not a simple way, but you can do it with a little bit of javascript. I can maybe work something up if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you @thesublimeobject I'll give it a go with some javascript to see if I can figure it out. Shame this cannot be achieved with CSS :( really appreciated your time replying.

Comment: It might not be very helpful, but I posted some code in my answer that I once used for doing that with the navbar. Maybe it could at least give you a start.

Comment: Awesome thanks @thesublimeobject I'm going to give it a go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute or fixed positioned element have their automatically calculated width calculated as “shrink-to-fit”, meaning they are only as wide as their content requires.

So *give* your navigation an explicit width, or position it from both “sides”, using `left:0; right:0`.

(And your `text-align:center` was of course not “overridden”, but just had no *visible* effect – *because* the element was only as wide as its content required, and then there *is* nothing more to “center” …)

Comment: This is a really good explanation, I'd just had a play with setting these positions and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting very detailed, [here is a codepen for you](http://codepen.io/thesublimeobject/pen/CIxfn). You need to add the fixed positioning and background to the parent element, .header, not the child elements.

Here is some possible js for the other activity:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var s = $("nav");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
            $('#rewrap').addClass("bump");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
            $('#rewrap').removeClass("bump");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a weird error in javascript! I have most of it working with my variables but swapped out the css for console messages so I can test. But I keep getting: [Error] TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'pos.top') in the console. Does this ring any bells?

Comment: This was from a site I did over a year ago, give me a few minutes and I'll see if I can get you an answer.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate that error, but maybe you forgot to replace one of the variables? That error is usually associated with not being able to find the element in the DOM. (Also if it helps #rewrap was my id for the content below the header. I probably should have said that before.)

Comment: I put the code into the javascript of this fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/du7NN/2/ As you can see I've stripped out most of it just for testing and only using 'nav' which is still there. I've probably typed something wrong! thanks anyway :)

Comment: @calibi Here I worked this up really quickly with your code: http://codepen.io/thesublimeobject/pen/FxHsJ. You had a couple of small mistakes in your conversion with js, but you also needed to have the nav bar set to relative first, and then switch it to fixed as you can see with the classes I added. I hope this helps a little bit more. Sorry it's taken us so long to get here!

Comment: Don't apologise, that worked perfectly! I understand how, I had a few mistakes in my syntax. That is such a lovely effect. Cheers!